# mocking multiple jdbcTemplate.queryForObject doesn'twork

Tags: java, mocking, jdbctemplate

my problem is that if I mock jdbcTemplate.queryForObject() 3 times, only the first mock works the 2 other mocks return with null. What is wrong with this code? Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
 //this works correctly and returns 1 
 Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(eq("select count(*) from TEST_TABLE_1"), (MapSqlParameterSource) any(), eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(1);
//this returns null        
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(eq("select count(*) from TEST_TABLE_11"),(MapSqlParameterSource) any(), eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(2);
//this returns null as well
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(eq("select count(*) from TEST_TABLE_111"), (MapSqlParameterSource) any(), eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(3);
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should rather mock once and not multiple times the same object, but you do not mock using a result but using a method

```
  Mockito.when( jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(any()), (MapSqlParameterSource) any(), eq(Integer.class)))).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
   Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
   Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    Object mock = invocation.getMock();
    if(//here you check if test_1 or 11 or...){
      return 1;//depending on the arg
   }
});
```

Comment: Mockito.when( jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(any(), (MapSqlParameterSource) any(), eq(Integer.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer( InvocationOnMock invocation ) {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                Object mock = invocation.getMock();
                if (args[0].toString().contentEquals("select count(*) from TEST_TABLE_1")) {
                    return 1;
                }                         
                ...
                return null;
            }
        });